# How to not make information save to database-ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I validate & potentially charge Credit Card details server side (in the Create function below) without saving these details to a database.

**Create ActionResult**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new Payment();
    model.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;
    return View(new Payment());

}

// POST: Payments/Create


[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,CardName,CardNumber,ValidFrom,Expires,CardSecurityCode,EmailAddress,ConfrimEmailAddress,Address,City,Country,PostCode")]  PaymentViewModel paymentViewModel ,Payment payment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                payment = new Payment();
                payment.EmailAddress = paymentViewModel.EmailAddress;
                payment.ConfrimEmailAddress = paymentViewModel.ConfirmEmailAddress;
                payment.Address = paymentViewModel.Address;
                payment.City = paymentViewModel.City;
                payment.Country = paymentViewModel.Country;
                payment.PostCode = paymentViewModel.PostCode;
                db.Payments.Add(payment);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", "Payments", new { id = payment.ID });
            }

            return View(paymentViewModel);
        }
```

**Model**

```
public class Payment
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]

    public string CardName { get; set; }
    // ------------------------------Visa Card ---------------------------------------------//
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{12}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{14}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{15}|564182[0-9]{10}|564182[0-9]{12}|564182[0-9]{13}|633110[0-9]{10}|633110[0-9]{12}|633110[0-9]{13}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Card Number You Paki")]


    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Valid From"), DataType(DataType.Date) DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM}")]
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Valid From"), DataType(DataType.Date) DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM}")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public string CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]

    public string ConfrimEmailAddress { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Address")]

    public string Address { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
{
    public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; } //creates a donation database

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<CharitySite.Models.Charity> Charities { get; set; }
}
```

I need to be able to retrive the Credit Card numbers without storing them in the database. Our original idea was to validate Credit Card Details client side using Javascript but project requirements dictate that server sided validation is performed.

Comment: Why are you setting `model.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;` and then ignore it and return another model? The web is stateless. If you do not save the data somewhere, then its gone.

Comment: `public string CardNumber { get; set; }`  Why not remove CardNumber from your model if you're never going to get or set it?

Comment: What do you want to do with Credit Card numbers? When you want to use them? On server code? on Database code? Is it just to validate them? Clarify the purpose of your code.

Comment: @Balde, The informations in the model is used only for validation purposes.

Comment: Then you need to use a ViewModel. Check my answer.

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code, I sincerely hope you're not using this in production. If you are, please contact me at the email listed on my profile and I'll give you a free quick code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to save a part of the information, and use the rest only for validation purposes (eg, validate the number of credit card), then you must use a ViewModel that contains all the information requested on the form, and extract from the ViewModel only the information you need save:

**ViewModel:**

```
public class PaymentViewModel
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]

    public string CardName { get; set; }
    // ------------------------------Visa Card ---------------------------------------------//
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{12}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{14}|(4903|4905|4911|4936|6333|6759)[0-9]{15}|564182[0-9]{10}|564182[0-9]{12}|564182[0-9]{13}|633110[0-9]{10}|633110[0-9]{12}|633110[0-9]{13}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Card Number You Paki")]


    public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Valid From"), DataType(DataType.Date) DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM}")]
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Valid From"), DataType(DataType.Date) DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM}")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public string CardSecurityCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]

    public string ConfrimEmailAddress { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Address")]

    public string Address { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Model (only containing fields to save):**

```
public class Payment
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    [Compare("EmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "The email and confirmation email do not match.")]

    public string ConfrimEmailAddress { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Address")]

    public string Address { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"\b\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?\b+", ErrorMessage = "Invalid postcode")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentDBContext : DbContext //controls information in database 
    {
        public DbSet<Payment> Payments { get; set; } //creates a donation database

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<CharitySite.Models.Charity> Charities { get; set; }
    }
```

**Create Action:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(PaymentViewModel paymentViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Some validation on credit card before save payment...

            // Save payment
            payment = new Payment();
            payment.EmailAddress = paymentViewModel.EmailAddress;
            payment.ConfirmEmailAddress = paymentViewModel.ConfirmEmailAddress;
            payment.Address = paymentViewModel.Address;
            payment.City = paymentViewModel.City;
            payment.Country = paymentViewModel.Country
            payment.PostCode = paymentViewModel.PostCode;
            db.Payments.Add(payment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Payments", new { id = payment.ID });
        }

        return View(paymentViewModel);
    }
```

**And change the Model used in your View:**

```
@model [yourNameSpace].paymentViewModel
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, should I delete the [Bind(Include = "ID,CardName,CardNumber,ValidFrom,Expires,CardSecurityCode,EmailAddress,ConfrimEmailAddress,Address,City,Country,PostCode")] Payment payment from the Create Brackets?

Comment: Yes. In ViewModels, you only inlcude the fields that you want to request from the form.  ViewModels is better than Bind to prevent overposting.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware there is no legislation actively prohibiting you from storing Credit Card details. Though certain aspects of your implementation may fail PCI compliance. For example, you *may* store the credit card number and expiry date but this must be in an encrypted form, you may **NEVER** store the CCV in any form.

Either way it isn't really recommended that you take on the burden of storing CC numbers, unless you have considerable experience and compliance budget. The only advantage I can really see to this is the consumer convenience of not having to repeatedly enter details. Most payment processors should allow you pass details to them for charging. If you choose this approach you may want to look into usage of the [SecureString class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) which will allow you to dispose of details as soon as you have transmitted them to the processor.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question.  OP is asking how to not save them to the database.

Comment: And I answered that. OP can prevent saving CC details to the database by  only keeping them in RAM, immediately passing them over to the payment processor, then by using the securestring class dispose of anything residing in memory.

Comment: The expiration date is also needs to be encrypted.

Comment: @Jamie - my point is that you don't specifically address the implementation.  The OP includes code for how the CC number is being saved to the db.  You've provided a link to a class. There is a large gap between the two.